# XPath for Assertion Token

Tags: php, soap, xpath, saml

I am writing a PHP script which needs to get an `Assertion` token as part of a process to log into *SharePoint* online. I am able to get an envelope response which includes the token I need.

How would I parse out the `saml:Assertion` portion of this response?

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RSTR/Issue</a:Action>
    <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2014-07-01T13:50:22.480Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2014-07-01T13:55:22.480Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
      <t:Lifetime>
        <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2014-07-01T13:50:22.476Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2014-07-01T14:50:22.476Z</wsu:Expires>
      </t:Lifetime>
      <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
        <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
          <wsa:Address>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:EndpointReference>
      </wsp:AppliesTo>
      <t:RequestedSecurityToken>
        <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" AssertionID="_56f0eee3-ca21-4885-a40d-4ae543e9bfc8" Issuer="http://paychex.com/adfs/services/trust/" IssueInstant="2014-07-01T13:50:22.480Z">
          <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2014-07-01T13:50:22.476Z" NotOnOrAfter="2014-07-01T14:50:22.476Z">
            <saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
              <saml:Audience>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</saml:Audience>
            </saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
          </saml:Conditions>
          <saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Subject>
              <saml:NameIdentifier Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">qo3X1/EAe0Ci5pXaS+p8JA==</saml:NameIdentifier>
              <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
              </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
            </saml:Subject>
            <saml:Attribute AttributeName="UPN" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims">
              <saml:AttributeValue>email@email.com</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute AttributeName="ImmutableID" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveID/Federation/2008/05">
              <saml:AttributeValue>qo3X1/p8JA==</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
          </saml:AttributeStatement>
          <saml:AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:password" AuthenticationInstant="2014-07-01T13:50:22.473Z">
            <saml:Subject>
              <saml:NameIdentifier Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">qo3X1/EAe0p8JA==</saml:NameIdentifier>
              <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
              </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
            </saml:Subject>
          </saml:AuthenticationStatement>
          <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
              <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
              <ds:Reference URI="#_56f0eee3-ca21-4885-a40d-4ae543e9bfc8">
                <ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                  <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>ZzoryFYQWfks=</ds:DigestValue>
              </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>UnHrvM3vUE6l4HlpsuBX7E79750MNWASBuVNIVJ01QJSID8w3IHkjfMWCjidty7F96obL5Ah6o/UY55dMjbiyWt9gyToQPrGBPjG+VX3pEz8XpXV4jrYYXJ/YMpHxdzD/OBzR/bpA+lzebkuP19woqV49ScmJ5TN4b26LEW/ynogYnNl7EEBAJR0wL9CjY6uQCNaERY0X29nyNusQyNTNW4jGeMyBu9KnfVRpVyROd4QxfwV/F8OwGlePRGPypN/VYnLRjfizS674XJ31VmLERwxgn5Xx/0bKDsNw7c5G2qFZmSi7YUxccwMxU6Ypih7D5i73uPrk7oMnRbMHsyxCQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
              <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>MIIC3DCCAcSgAwIBAgIQXIfoKmHCypFBv4Ze44WbzzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAqMSgwJgYDVQQDEx9BREZTIFNpZ25pbmcgLSBhZGZzLnBheWNoZXguY29tMB4XDTE0MDQyNDAyMDY1NloXDTE5MDQyMzAyMDY1NlowKjEoMCYGA1UEAxMfQURkhc6NJSB8fJK+Uf/ldkC8VISTp7CW9S3TwXHKn4plqMLSY7NRYII4OPDkLXA9dGx3FQGNQoTe/uH1JGaNZlAGJp4W2Sz9r1i9Ry4lu+L0G3Q==</X509Certificate>
              </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
          </ds:Signature>
        </saml:Assertion>
      </t:RequestedSecurityToken>
      <t:RequestedAttachedReference>
        <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:k="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" k:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1">
          <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID">_56f0eee3-ca21-4885-a40d-4ae543e9bfc8</o:KeyIdentifier>
        </o:SecurityTokenReference>
      </t:RequestedAttachedReference>
      <t:RequestedUnattachedReference>
        <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:k="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" k:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1">
          <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID">_56f0eee3-ca21-4885-a40d-4ae543e9bfc8</o:KeyIdentifier>
        </o:SecurityTokenReference>
      </t:RequestedUnattachedReference>
      <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>
      <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
      <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>
    </t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

My PHP code snippet to parse this response is:

```
// Parse security token from response
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($result);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$nodelist = $xpath->query("/*[local-name()='name']:Body/*[local-name()='name']:RequestSecurityTokenResponse/*[local-name()='name']:RequestedSecurityToken/*[local-name()='name']:Assertion");

foreach ($nodelist as $n){
    return $n->nodeValue;
    break;
}
```

Thanks for all your help,
Tim

Comment: What exactly is your problem with getting the value? Just to get the element is the simplest possible XPath location step `/*:Body/*:RequestSecurityTokenResponse/*:RequestedSecurityToken/*:Assertion` if you ignore namespaces and just use the wildcard operator `*`

Comment: I tried using //saml:Assertion but it did not work. When I tried your xpath, I got this error message:

PHP Warning:  DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in /opt/ibm/si/SharePoint/testADFS.php on line 44
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/ibm/si/SharePoint/testADFS.php on line 46

Comment: Hmm I also tried:

/*[local-name()='name']:Body/*[local-name()='name']:RequestSecurityTokenResponse/*[local-name()='name']:RequestedSecurityToken/*[local-name()='name']:Assertion

Comment: I'd would be advisable if you also provide your PHP code snippet. Your XPath is correct, I'd guess you didn't bind the namespace or did not do so correctly. Normally, I would expect this PHP library expect to also support wildcards, but I am not familiar with PHP (but they should, it is standard XPath 1.0)

Comment: @dirkk `prefix:*` is allowed in XPath 1.0 but `*:localname` is 2.0-only.

Comment: @IanRoberts Really? uuh, thanks, I didn't know that. Good to know, I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using //saml:Assertion but it did not work

You need to register the namespace prefix first - XPath expressions do not care what prefixes were used in the original document, you need to bind prefixes to namespaces yourself.

```
$xpath->registerNamespace("s", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion");
$nodelist = $xpath->query("//s:Assertion");
```

But this will probably still give you null because the "node value" of an element node in the DOM is defined in the spec to always be null.  If you want the text inside an element node then you need to use `textContent` instead of `nodeValue`, but in this case you'll probably have to dig deeper into the tree to find the bit you actually want.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me. My code snippet is:

    // Parse security token from response
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->loadXML($result);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
    $xpath->registerNamespace("s", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion");
    $nodelist = $xpath->query("//s:Assertion");

    foreach ($nodelist as $n){
        return $n->nodeValue;
        break;
    }

Comment: @user1472409 `nodeValue` is almost certainly the wrong thing to be extracting there, what _exactly_ are you trying to pull out of this XML document?

Comment: I am actually trying to pull everything from <saml:Assertion> to </saml:Assertion>, including those two tags.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: @user1472409 You are already extracting the node. You just have to now get the contents of its elements or attributes.

Comment: Unless you have many `Assertion` objects in a response (which doesn't seem to be the case since your `for` actually returns the first value), you could use `->item(0)` to get the first node. In that case you can write expressions which directly get what you want. To get the certificate key text for example, you could use: `$key_cert = $xpath->query("//s:X509Certificate")->item(0)->textContent` (assuming there is only one `X509Certificate` per document)

Comment: That's actually in a different namespace (not the same one registered for `Assertion`). Add `$xpath->registerNamespace("dsig", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")` and use `dsig:X509Certificate`. Register the other namespaces you might use as well. Here is a fiddle using this solution to get the `X509Certificate` contents: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Bro32Y

Comment: @helderdarocha Thank you so much for your help. I am getting close. I was able to get all the values within the <t:RequestedSecurityToken> field by doing this:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/bAQqME

However, I would like to get the full XML within those fields. Do you know of a way to do that? Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

To simply extract the value, in XPath 1.0 you can use the following expression, which *ignores* namespaces:

```
/*[local-name()='Envelope']
   /*[local-name()='Body']
      /*[local-name()='RequestSecurityTokenResponse']
         /*[local-name()='RequestedSecurityToken']
            /*[local-name()='Assertion']
```

or using the descendant axis:

```
//*[local-name()='Assertion']
```

*Ignoring* namespaces should be a second option. If you can register them as suggested by @IanRoberts in the other answer it is better.

Any of these expressions will return a *node-set* containing all the `Assertion` elements found (the whole tree). The node value or text content of these nodes may not be what you want to select. For example, if you want to get the `X509Certificate` you should use a contextual XPath expression to that element and extract its `text()`. Same strategy should be used if you want an attribute of a child element.

**Update** The PHP code you added uses a for loop just to extract the first node. You could use `item(0)` for that. Assuming there is only one assertion, key, certificate, etc, in each document, you can use XPath expressions to extract exactly what you want. For example, to get the `X509Certificate` text (ignoring namespaces and intermediate location steps) you could use:

```
$key_cert = $xpath->query("//*[local-name()='X509Certificate']")->item(0)->textContent
```

Comment: Please don't do this. It looks _horrible_. What is the benefit of using `/*[local-name()='Body']` over `*:Body`?

Comment: You are correct. Urgh, still, that's incredibly ugly - But not your fault.